# Converting CURL request to HTTP Request Java?

Tags: java, android, curl, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I have the following CURL request Can anyone please confirm me what would be the subesquest HTTP Request

```
curl 'http://192.168.2.1/apply.cgi' -H 'Host: 192.168.2.1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Referer: http://192.168.2.1/Status_file.html' -u admin:admin -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'submit_button=Status_Router&submit_type=Disconnect_pppoe&change_action=gozila_cgi&ethwanpppoe=0&wait_time=3'
```

Will it be something like ?

```
    URL myurl = new URL("http://192.168.2.1/apply.cgi");
    String userPassword = "admin" + ":" + "admin";
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userPassword.getBytes()));
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", "192.168.2.1");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://192.168.2.1/Status_file.html");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.connect();
    final OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    osw.write("submit_button=Status_Router&submit_type=Disconnect_pppoe&change_action=gozila_cgi&ethwanpppoe=0&wait_time=3");
    osw.close();
```

Can anyone be kind enough to help me convert the above curl request completely to httpreq.

Thanks in advance.

Erkan

Comment: Properties with `-H` are Header properties you should set them as header

Comment: Why not listen for curl output with `tcpdump`?

Comment: I'm not sure you should replicate that request just by sending the same headers.  You are advertising support for gzip and deflate, but not handling that yourself.

Why not use a library like OkHttp and send just the headers you need?

Comment: you have already converted curl into HTTP. are you getting any issue in this code?

Comment: sounds good what is the problem exactly?